# Display a popup message if no results found from parse.com query

Tags: xcode, parse-platform

I am creating an application in Xcode using parse.com. I am currently performing queries on the parse database from a series of menu buttons. I want to display a message to the user via a UIAltertView if there are no results found based on their selection.

Currently my table view controller just shows up blank cells if there are no results based on the query.

How could I structure the syntax for number of results = 0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override `objectsDidLoad`.

**Swift**

```
override func objectsDidLoad(error: NSError!) {
    super.objectsDidLoad(error)

    if(self.objects.count == 0){
        //Present UIAlertController
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "No objects", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)objectsDidLoad:(NSError *)error {
    [super objectsDidLoad:error];

    if(self.objects.count == 0){
        //Present UIAlertView
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"No objects" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```